# Automatically redirect to SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my server is running an Apache server. So far, everything is okay. But if I try to force SSL trough .htaccess, Chrome/Firefox tells me: "this website redirect loops" or something like that.

I was using this code found here @ SO:

```
    RewriteEngine on 
First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Chrome says: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this result by setting up the http (rather than https) server to its own site directory which contained the following index.php:

```
<?php header("Location: https://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]); ?>
```

I realise this does not use apache's rewrite features (I am actually already using rewrite for something else and doing it that way would have complicated things), and obviously it'll only work if you're also running PHP, but it is a fairly simple solution. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is your SSL cover www.youdomain.com or just yourdomain.com ?

If you use www. you can try this in your .htaccess

> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Hi! I don't really know, at least I know that it's working if I call https://www & https://domain ... so?